# Chart that describes how full the pond is

Tags: civil-engineering, water-resources

when designing a pond it is customary to produce a chart for the local council, specifying the height of the water for the volume stored. What is the name of this chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storage curve or water supply curve are both possible depending on the planned use.